# Default knit directory via YAML header in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

**Is there a YAML option, which sets knit directory for an Rmd file?** I.e. does the same as illustrated in Fig.1. 
The problem is that every time I copy files or share a project with other people (which usually have different default RStudio options than I do), the knit directory should be reset manually in each file. 
I'm aware of the global option (Fig.2), but I need a more reproducible solution which works for individual Rmd files in both both RStudio notebook and knitting modes.
And, for instance, I know that there is an option such as:

```
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
```

Any ideas?

[image]

**Fig. 1** Setting knit directory via menu commands.

[image]

**Fig. 2** Global option to set default knit directory in RStudio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to specify the `knit` field in the front-matter of our .Rmd file. Example .Rmd that would knit into "some_dir" created in your home directory:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
    rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_dir = "~/some_dir/")
  })
---

# Some content

Some content
```

Comment: I was not aware of this functionality, which changes the output directory. It is useful.
Yet it is not the same, as "knit directory", which also changes the working directory.
@Jozef Could you provide a link where I could read more about YAML option `knit`?

Comment: `rmarkdown::render()` has more interesting options worth exploring. Thus, I accept your answer.

Comment: but how do you specifically refer to the `Project` directory, as the question suggests? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou, if you really want to refer to the current RStudio project directory you can use `output_dir = rstudioapi::getActiveProject()`, note that this will likely only work in an RStudio context though.

Comment: great, thanks @Jozef !! And nice blog by the way :-)

Comment: Magnificent! This has been very useful!